# Nohup command to run a script and get control immediately for next script

Tags: shell

I have used nohup command and execute a unix shell script from background but i want to execute the next command immediately before the previous shell script gets completed , i do not want to wait until and unless the shell script gets completed.

Is there any way , i tried with nohup but i m getting this:

nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'

and not getting control to run the next command. Is there any way to exit  immediatley after calling a shell script and let it run in the background , execute the next command without using CTRL+C or force shutdown.

I have used the below command but

$ nohup sh dataload.sh &
[1]     14472
$ nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
here I am not able to get the control to execute the next command

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in the background: `nohup your_command &`